# Unknown partition on SSD after dual boot

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I just wiped an old partition on my SSD for Ubuntu so I can install 17.10 (the update broke something, nothing worked, no one helped).

Next to the partition is another 7.87GB partition Windows just calls Healthy (Primary partition)

The recovery partition and Windows 100MB partition are there, any idea what the 8 gigs are for?

Comment: Old swap partition? What does gparted says?

Comment: Is Windows able to get the format type? If not, then use gparted from Ubuntu as Jean-Marie suggested. gparted will be able to recognize the different type of Linux partitions.